# Acer Aspire 6920G boots up to windows and then hangs, cursor moves, but doesn't respond

Tags: windows, windows-vista, acer-aspire

My Acer Aspire 6920G will boot up to Windows, but then it hangs, the cursor moves but it won't respond to any input.

It was running Vista, so I installed Windows 7, and it worked for a few days.

Then, in the middle of installing Office 2010, it hung again.

So, I tried installing Windows 7 again, but now it will not get past the "`Starting Windows...`" screen when booting from the Windows 7 install time.